# Commit working files you don't intend to push remotely?

Tags: git

I'm working on a wordpress project on wpengine with 3 development environments - Production, Staging and Development ( My local workspace ).

I've created a branch from my "Master" named "wpec-3.8.12" within my Development environment and checkout it out.

Within "wpec-3.8.12" i've updated the plugin wpecommerce to 3.8.12, which is currently in development.

[I've read that you need to commit changes before switching back to the master branch.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

What is done with working files you don't intend to push remotely? 
i.e - wpecommerce 3.8.12 plugin files.

Would i still commit these files before switching back to the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you commit changes to your local repo doesn't mean they have to be pushed. Your entire wpec-3.8.12 branch might never exist anywhere else if it's only for development. Once the development is complete, you can merge that branch back into master.

Presumably your master branch will be pushed to staging (and eventually to development).

This type of work-flow allows you to keep your various feature development and bugfix branches isolated locally, only merging the completed and tested code into master when it's ready to go to your staging/production remotes.

If you have temporary files such as caches or logs, you may not want those in the repository at all. If you never add them, they won't get committed; they will remain as untracked files. You can also list them explicitly in your .gitignore to prevent accidental commits by you or others. (Note that the .gitignore file should be pushed to remotes.)

Comment: Hi eaj, thanks for your reply. I'll add the wpecommerce plugin dir to .gitignore to ensure it doesn't get pushed to Staging or Production.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them tracked, don't add them to the repository. Untracked files will be ignored when you switch branches, unless you check out a branch where a file with the same name already exists, in which case the `checkout` will fail with an error message.

If these are temporary files that you don't want to track change to over time, you should definitely *not* add them before switching back to your `master` branch.

Comment: hi meagar, thanks for the reply. I checked out of my new branch "wpec-3.8.12" after making changes to the plugin files & without committing (or adding) those changes. Then i checked into the Master branch. I then refreshed my plugin page within the wordpress admin area, thinking wpecommerce would revert from 3.8.12 back to 3.8.11 . This didn't happen, not sure where i went wrong. I thought the files would return to the state i left them on the Master branch..